# how to import popup component to React-Native?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, cross-platform, popupwindow

I'm beginner in React-Native and I want to add a popup window to my app, I found this: https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-native-popup
I made the first step:

```
npm install react-native-popup --save
```

then whenever I import it to my project using this line and run it on my Android emulator:

```
import Popup from 'react-native-popup';
```

I get a red screen with this error:

> > seems you're trying to access 'ReactNative.Component' from the
> >     'react-native' package. Perhaps you meant to access 'React.Component'
> >     from the 'react' package instead? For example, instead of: import
> >     React, { Component, View} from 'react-native'; you should now do:
> >     import React, { Component } from 'react' import {View} from
> >     'react-native';

Although this is what I'm actually doing, here's my code:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import {
  AppRegistry,
  StyleSheet,
  Text,
  TouchableHighlight,
  View
} from 'react-native';
import Popup from 'react-native-popup';

class AwesomeProject3 extends Component {
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's not your error, it's that library, `react-native-popup`, it imports `React` from `react-native`, and that is really depricated.

I will suggest you to use React-Native's original `Modal` and `Alert` instead. They works perfect.

Comment: That's right `Alert` works perfectly and does the same thing. Thanks a lot.